# How to populate Dynamic array with Strings in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I am doing a project where I have to read in text from a file and then extract every word that is 4 characters long and allocate it into dynamic array.My approach is to create int function that will get number of 4 letter words and return that number , then create another function that will grab that number and create dynamic array consisting of that many elements. The problem with this approach is how to populate that array with words that meet the requirement.

```
int func1(FILE *pFile){

    int counter = 0;
    int words = 0;
    char inputWords[length];
    while(fscanf(pFile,"%s",inputWords) != EOF){
    if(strlen(inputWords)==4){
          #counting 4 letter words
          counter++;
           }
      }
 }
      return counter;
 }

   int main(){
    #creating pointer to a textFile
    FILE *pFile = fopen("smallDictionary.txt","r");
    int line = 0;  
    #sending pointer into a function   
    func1(pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What code have you written in attempts to solve your problem?

Comment: Put the code into the question as formatted text. Not in the comments where it is unreadable. And please describe what issues you are having with that code.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to populate my dynamic array with retrieved 4 letter words that I counted

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading lines of input with `fgets()`, and breaking each line into tokens with `strtok()`. As each token is found, the length can be checked, and if the token is four characters long it can be saved to an array using `strdup()`.

In the code below, storage is allocated for pointers to `char` which will store the addresses of four-letter words. `num_words` holds the number of four-letter words found, and `max_words` holds the maximum number of words that can currently be stored. When a new word needs to be added, `num_words` is incremented, and if there is not enough storage, more space is allocated. Then `strdup()` is used to duplicate the token, and the address is assigned to the next pointer in `words`.

Note that `strdup()` is not in the C Standard Library, but that it is POSIX. The feature test macro in the first line of the program may be needed to enable this function. Also note that `strdup()` allocates memory for the duplicated string which must be freed by the caller.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SZ     1000
#define ALLOC_INC  100

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[BUF_SZ];
    char **words = NULL;
    size_t num_words = 0;
    size_t max_words = 0;
    char *token;
    char *delims = " \t\r\n";

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(buffer, delims);

        while (token != NULL) {
            if (strlen(token) == 4) {
                ++num_words;
                if (num_words > max_words) {
                    max_words += ALLOC_INC;
                    char **temp = realloc(words, sizeof *temp * max_words);
                    if (temp == NULL) {
                        perror("Unable to allocate memory");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    words = temp;
                }
                words[num_words-1] = strdup(token);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
    }

    if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to close file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        puts(words[i]);
    }

    /* Free allocated memory */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);

    return 0;
}
```

### Update

OP has mentioned that nonstandard functions are not permitted in solving this problem. Though `strdup()` is POSIX, and both common and standard in this sense, it is not always available. In such circumstances it is common to simply implement `strdup()`, as it is straightforward to do so. Here is the above code, modified so that now the function `my_strdup()` is used in place of `strdup()`. The code is unchanged, except that the feature test macro has been removed, the call to `strdup()` has been changed to `my_strdup()`, and of course now there is a function prototype and a definition for `my_strdup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SZ     1000
#define ALLOC_INC  100

char * my_strdup(const char *);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[BUF_SZ];
    char **words = NULL;
    size_t num_words = 0;
    size_t max_words = 0;
    char *token;
    char *delims = " \t\r\n";

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
        token = strtok(buffer, delims);

        while (token != NULL) {
            if (strlen(token) == 4) {
                ++num_words;
                if (num_words > max_words) {
                    max_words += ALLOC_INC;
                    char **temp = realloc(words, sizeof *temp * max_words);
                    if (temp == NULL) {
                        perror("Unable to allocate memory");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    words = temp;
                }
                words[num_words-1] = my_strdup(token);
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }
    }

    if (fclose(fp) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to close file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        puts(words[i]);
    }

    /* Free allocated memory */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);

    return 0;
}

char * my_strdup(const char *str)
{

    size_t sz = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *dup = malloc(sizeof *dup * sz);

    if (dup) {
        strcpy(dup, str);
    }

    return dup;
}
```

### Final Update

OP had not posted code in the question when the above solution was written. The posted code does not compile as is. In addition to missing `#include`s and various syntax errors (extra braces, incorrect comment syntax) there are a couple of more significant issues. In `func1()`, the `length` variable is used uninitialized. This should be large enough so that `inputWords[]` can hold any expected word. Also, width specifiers should be used with `%s` in `scanf()` format strings to avoid buffer overflow. And, OP code should be checking whether the file opened successfully. Finally, `func1()` returns a value, but the calling function does not even assign this value to a variable.

To complete the task, the value returned from `func1()` should be used to declare a 2d array to store the four-letter words. The file can be rewound, but this time as `fscanf()` retrieves words in a loop, if a word has length `4`, `strcpy()` is used to copy the word into the array.

Here is a modified version of OP's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD  100

int func1(FILE *pFile){

    int counter = 0;
    char inputWords[MAX_WORD];

    while(fscanf(pFile,"%99s",inputWords) != EOF) {
        if(strlen(inputWords) == 4) {
          counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
 }

int main(void)
{
    FILE *pFile = fopen("filename.txt","r");
    if (pFile == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char inputWords[MAX_WORD];
    int num_4words = func1(pFile);
    char words[num_4words][MAX_WORD];
    int counter = 0;

    rewind(pFile);

    while(fscanf(pFile,"%99s",inputWords) != EOF) {
        if(strlen(inputWords) == 4) {
          strcpy(words[counter], inputWords);
          counter++;
        }
    }

    if (fclose(pFile) != 0) {
        perror("Unable to close file");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_4words; i++) {
        puts(words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid I am not allowed to use non standard C libraries
@David Bowling

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that `strdup()` is nonstandard. As I said, it is POSIX, and is quite common, e.g., on every Linux system. But, you can easily write an implementation of it, and these are also easy to find with Google (and here on SO). I will add one to the answer.

Comment: @MaciejGirek-- I have added a version that includes an implementation of `strdup()`, and thus only relies on functions from the C Standard Library.

Comment: @MaciejGirek-- there was no code posted in your question when I wrote my answer. I have commented on this code and provided a solution that makes use of your existing code.